# transfer file from local machine of 1 cluster to hdfs of another cluster

Tags: shell, unix, hadoop

I have 2 hadoop clusters(A and B) and want to transfer a file from local of cluster A to HDFS of cluster B. Is there a way to do it?

I tried copyFromLocal and put but looks like they don't copy the file over to the HDFS of cluster B and show that they are not supported:
`copyFromLocal: Not supported`

fyi: connection looks open as I am able to read HDFS of cluster B from local of cluster A(hadoop fs -ls hdfs://NNofB:port/path)

Comment: forgot to mention that all commands need to be fired from local of A only.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a direct way from HDFS->HDFS, but you could `get` from HDFS on a node in ClusterA, `scp` the data to a node in ClusterB, then `put` that data into HDFS from that node in ClusterB.

Comment: ah, actually for HDFS->HDFS i am able to do a distcp. But for Local->HDFS(of other cluster) I need to figure out a way to do it without accessing cluster B.

Comment: `ssh` into a cluster B node?

Comment: yeah, thats the problem. We have password entry so ssh into cluster B will not work as this will be done through a shared script. Would have otherwise created a script to do this with the credentials. :(